# WPF Binding problem

Tags: binding

I have a class structure as follows :

```
public class Person
{
    public PersonInfo Details { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonInfo
{
    public string Designation { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying bind 2 textBoxes as follows:

```
Person person = new Person();

textBox1.DataContext = person;
textBox2.DataContext = person;

Binding textBox1Binding = new Binding()
{
   Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource,
   Path = new PropertyPath("Name"),
};

Binding textBox1Binding = new Binding()
{
   Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource,
   **Path = new PropertyPath("Details.Designation")**   << problem is here
};
```

How to bind "Details.Designation" to textbox2 ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It took some time, but I think I have a solution. Your PersonInfo-Object in Person does not exist. I modified your code to the following and now it works for me

```
  public class Person
  {
    private PersonInfo pi;

    public Person()
    {
      pi = new PersonInfo();
    }

    public PersonInfo Details
    {
      get
      {
        return pi;
      }
      set
      {
        pi = value;
      }
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public class PersonInfo
  {
    public string Designation { get; set; }
  }
```

And somewhere:

```
  textBox1.DataContext = person;
  textBox2.DataContext = person;

  Binding textBox1Binding = new Binding()
  {
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource,
    Path = new PropertyPath("Name"),
  };
  textBox1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, textBox1Binding);

  Binding textBox2Binding = new Binding()
  {
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource,
    Path = new PropertyPath("Details.Designation"),
  };
  textBox2.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, textBox2Binding);
```

Can you ensure that your Sub-Object 'PersonInfo' (via Property Designation) exists before binding?